# How to find out value given by etherscan api

Tags: etherscan

I tried out to get a transaction using the etherscan API, but it seems, that the value of the transaction, as well as pretty much everyhthing about the transaction is encoded. I really do not understand how I might be able to find out the real value from this. Maybe somebody is able to help me

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0", 
    "id": 1, 
    "result": {
        "blockHash": "0x84d7a319a6dbbf8c7f6fd5d3ad7ff8af656823b9150b3b16e62a959209402f66", 
        "blockNumber": "0xd86677", 
        "from": "0x650e035584ec7d44ee1e798e02c55508674e0ef2", 
        "gas": "0x5208", 
        "gasPrice": "0x16deabeae3", 
        "maxFeePerGas": "0x1c5d4d32b0", 
        "maxPriorityFeePerGas": "0x59682f00", 
        "hash": "0x53eeef5726e9b89b47eb0876da44ba2cb9622605d2d60616632d4511bae0c48f", 
        "input": "0x", 
        "nonce": "0x16", 
        "to": "0xc2e9b6cc2e9e47a72c1c4c78b0d6e9e73dbfc277", 
        "transactionIndex": "0x8e", 
        "value": "0x8e1bc9bf040000", 
        "type": "0x2", 
        "accessList": [], 
        "chainId": "0x1", 
        "v": "0x0", 
        "r": "0x273b057fd3819987f7c89c0ba5fe690c98335ef35cc1a2972b392e2c3f102ebe", 
        "s": "0x7eba6b02576e67112584ade4f356877c3bbf67de70bef4f74630bd6a4e1892d8"
    }
    
}
```

Comment: value is the hex of the amount of ether that is transferred in WEI. if you are calling a smart contract then the data transferred to the contract is in "input" and you need the contract code to decode it easily. v r s are the singature... you need to understand what inside a transaction  and then you can decode the data :) and for contract data you need contract code. but this tx has no input so it is only ether transfer from 0x650e035584ec7d44ee1e798e02c55508674e0ef2 to 0xc2e9b6cc2e9e47a72c1c4c78b0d6e9e73dbfc277

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start here :) it will help you to understand what are those keys and then you can understand the values and decode them

https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/transactions/
https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/blocks/

examples:

Value: is the hex of the amount of ether that is transferred in WEI.

Input: if you are calling a smart contract then the data transferred to the contract is in "input" and you need the contract code to decode it easily.

v, r, s: are the signature

nonce: is the number of the transaction

chainId: the id of the blockchain. ethereum mainnet has id 1 = 0x1

This Transaction has no input so I assume it is only ether transfer 0.04 from 0x650e035584ec7d44ee1e798e02c55508674e0ef2 to 0xc2e9b6cc2e9e47a72c1c4c78b0d6e9e73dbfc277

Comment: Thank you that was a big help, but I don't really get yet, how I can get the original amount I transferred?

Comment: @CyberguyGame It is in „value“ convert that from hex-decimal to decimal and then decimal from Wei to Ether

Comment: I can write make a picture of that tomorrow on my laptop